# KeyError: 'iface'

Tags: python-2.7, tcp, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
ip = IP(dst='127.0.0.1')
tcp = TCP(dport=80, iface='wlan0')
```

The error is `KeyError: 'iface'` who showed in image.
[**erro_scapy_iface**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWlQx.png)

Answer (score 0):

The options for the `TCP` class are [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/365ea83be68426e42b1744c1fa52df0e885f7854/scapy/layers/inet.py#L512). There is no `iface` option. You can check it also with `ls`:

```
>>> ls(IP)
version    : BitField (4 bits)                   = (4)
ihl        : BitField (4 bits)                   = (None)
tos        : XByteField                          = (0)
len        : ShortField                          = (None)
id         : ShortField                          = (1)
flags      : FlagsField (3 bits)                 = (0)
frag       : BitField (13 bits)                  = (0)
ttl        : ByteField                           = (64)
proto      : ByteEnumField                       = (0)
chksum     : XShortField                         = (None)
src        : SourceIPField (Emph)                = (None)
dst        : DestIPField (Emph)                  = (None)
options    : PacketListField                     = ([])
>>> ls(TCP)
sport      : ShortEnumField                      = (20)
dport      : ShortEnumField                      = (80)
seq        : IntField                            = (0)
ack        : IntField                            = (0)
dataofs    : BitField (4 bits)                   = (None)
reserved   : BitField (3 bits)                   = (0)
flags      : FlagsField (9 bits)                 = (2)
window     : ShortField                          = (8192)
chksum     : XShortField                         = (None)
urgptr     : ShortField                          = (0)
options    : TCPOptionsField                     = ({})
```

The [`sniff`, `send`, `sendp`](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=iface#interactive-tutorial) (and maybe others) commands have an`iface` kwargs, as explained in the **interactive tutorial**.